# AngularJs: Searching with ng-repeat with two different controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular app using two tables. The top table is supposed to search for data for both tables, however, they are using two different controllers.  How can I get the top table to do this using a simple service or factory?

```
div ng-controller="topCtrl">
     <tr ng-repeat="data in myData | filter:search">
          <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
          <td>{{ data.number }}</td>
          <td>{{ data.street }}</td>
      </tr>
 </div>

 div ng-controller="botCtrl">
     <tr ng-repeat="data in myData2 | filter:search2">
          <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
          <td>{{ data.number }}</td>
          <td>{{ data.street }}</td>
      </tr>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include the service directly into your searchQuery

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uslperera/9xxz1ju3/38/)

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('topCtrl', function topCtrl($scope, searchService) {
    $scope.myData = ["A", "B"];
    $scope.searchService = searchService;
});

angular.module('myApp').controller('botCtrl', function botCtrl($scope, searchService) {
    $scope.myData2 = ["A", "B"];
    $scope.searchService = searchService;
});
```

---

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="topCtrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="searchService.search"/>
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="data in myData | filter:searchService.search">
                <td>{{ data }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div ng-controller="botCtrl">
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="data in myData2 | filter:searchService.search">
                <td>{{ data }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```